# copying static array to dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

So I was playing around with some basics in c++ when I noticed this:

```
int * ptr = new int[3], arr[3] = { 11,13,15 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr[i];

cout << ptr[0] << ' ' << ptr[1] << ' ' << ptr[2] << endl;
```

this code will perfectly insert and print out the values: 11 13 15.

Whereas when I write it this way:

```
int size=0, * ptr = new int[size], arr[3] = { 11,13,15 };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ptr = new int[++size];
    ptr[i] = arr[i];
}
cout << ptr[0] << ' ' << ptr[1] << ' ' << ptr[2] << endl;
```

When I increment the size one value at a time, it prints out:

-842150451 -842150451 15

Why is it that when I define the total size at the beginning, the values are properly inserted, however when I increment one step at a time it does not? Also, is there any way to write the second code but in a way where it works please?

Comment: In each iteration you are allocating a new array. In 1st iteration allocate new array of size 1 you set its 0th index value to arr[0], 2nd again new array of size 2, set it's 1st index value to arr[1], 3rd iteration new array of size 3, set it's 2nd index value to arr[2].

Comment: cout just see your last instantiated object of int array and it just has one valid member which is ptr[2] and ptr[0] and ptr[1] does not have a initialized value

Comment: Tip: When you see a weird number like -842150451, especially when it repeats, turn it into hex and see if the program is trying to tell you something. In hex you get CDCDCDCD, and that's also too repetitious to be an accident. Looking it up in [a table of common debug codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values), we find that it's a  common code for uninitialized heap memory, and you could have used that information to help track down the problem.

Comment: `ptr = new int[++size];` does not simply resize what `ptr` points at. It increments the variable `size` and allocates a completely NEW block of memory that is unrelated to the old value of `ptr`. That new block is uninitialised. The old block of memory is simply leaked - the pointer to it is overwritten, so the old memory cannot be accessed. The statement `ptr[i] = arr[i]` then copies a single value from `arr[i]` to `ptr[i]`, leaving all previous elements (`ptr[0]` to `ptr[i-1]`) UNINITIALIZED.  Printing the elements after the loop accesses uninitialised elements, so has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ch3esteR points out in the comment. The problem is that you are reallocating your
array on each iteration, and thereby zeroing (or in your case, catching some random
values on the heap).

I would say that the bigger solution might be to use standard containers for handling memory. [Here is a solution](https://godbolt.org/z/fvccMz7En) for fixing your original code `original()` and a proposed alternative for how to handle dynamic arrays with std::vector.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void original() {
    const int arr[3] = { 11,13,15 };

    const int size=3;
    auto ptr = new int[size]; // this is what you want to do
    std::copy(arr, arr + size, ptr); // Standard function for copying

    cout << ptr[0] << ' ' << ptr[1] << ' ' << ptr[2] << endl;
}

int main() {
    original();

    const int arr[3] = { 11,13,15 }; // You might want to make this a std::vector too

    std::vector<int> result{arr, arr + 3};

    // std::vector<int> result;  // Or if the question was how to do it dynamically
    // for (auto i: arr)
    // {
    //     result.push_back(i); // Dynamic add
    // }

    cout << result[0] << ' ' << result[1] << ' ' << result[2] << endl;
}
```

On request: How to do it with pointers (don't do this unless you have some external constraint that forces you to do this, like a teacher)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Reallocate memory and delete the old pointer
int *resize(int *arr, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize) {
    auto newArr = new int[newSize];

    auto copySize = std::min(oldSize, newSize); // Handle both growing and shrinking resize
    std::copy(arr, arr + copySize, newArr); // Copy your old data
    // Or do it like this
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < copySize, ++i) {
    //    newArray[i] = arr[i]
    // }

    delete [] arr;

    return newArr;

}

int main() {
    auto arr = new int[2] { 11,13 }; // Observe 'new' here
    size_t size = 3;

    // "resize" the array arr (in practice you are just creating a new one)
    arr = resize(arr, size, size + 1);

    // Assign your new value
    arr[2] = 14;


    cout << arr[0] << ' ' << arr[1] << ' ' << arr[2] << endl;

    delete [] arr; // Remember, try to not manual memory management,
                   // only use it in class when you are learning the basics, otherwise use
                   // std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr
}
```

Comment: I see what u mean, just we didnt go through in class the concept of containers just yet. I do realize that the containers are a lot simpler to use. but is there anyway to do so only using pointers pls?

Comment: @Lasersköld The code where you add elements to the vector in a for loop is kind of inefficient! As you know the size of the vector before inserting, you should allocate enouth space for it. Your code will reallocate the vector some times. This won't be a big deal for three elements, but I wanted just to make you aware of it.

Comment: @NessyaNakache as you are programming C++ and not C, you should consider to learn how to use STL-Containers. The usage is pretty simple and well documented here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container
I should mention, that you can treat Iterators just like raw pointers. (When starting with their usage, later you should understand what Iterators really are!)

Comment: I do agree. I did learn STL containers just they havent covered it yet in class and will penalize points from my homework if i add anything too advanced. I also dont want to add a large static array that will take up unnecessary space

Comment: @Bananenkönig I know about the performance penalty, but the question was about how to add dynamically to an array. But I agree with you, its a bit sad if you need to use the wrong tools for the job in a class.

Comment: @NessyaNakache Now I added a example that uses raw pointers. If your teacher does not accept that, you might want to send them to this thread and ask if it is really c++ you are learning.